# How is inlining performed with extern inline in C?

Tags: c

How does the C compiler do inlining when a file contains an `extern inline` declaration?

I've read a couple of posts on StackOverflow regarding `extern inline`, and still, I do not quite understand how the below pattern works? Some posts say that we need to have the inline definition in the header file, and then the corresponding `extern inline` declaration in the source file as I showed below.

foo.h:

```
inline void foo(void) { ... }
```

foo.c:

```
#include "foo.h"
extern inline void foo(void);
int main(void) {
  foo();
}
```

My question is that how does the compiler perform the inlining when compiling with like -O1 flag since, after the preprocessing, the inline definition would be added to the source file, and in this translation unit, we have the `extern inline` which actually changes the original inline definition of the function `foo` to an external definition and this cannot be used for inlining at all. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: The `inline` keyword is just a suggestion, and compilers are free to ignore it. See some comments at cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/inline with references to C standards.

Comment: `extern` says that a function is visible outside the compilation unit. `inline` says that calls to the function should, if possible, be inlined. There’s no contradiction: if the compiler/linker can see the function definition, it’s free to inline calls to the function. `extern` just says that it *also* has to generate an out-of-line definition, which can be used in cases where no function inlining takes place (and for dynamic linking). I don’t know where you are getting the idea that “this cannot be used for inlining at all”. It *can*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Because I thought only "inline definition" can be inlined, just from the literal meaning.

Comment: @Becavalier The compiler is actually allowed to inline whatever it wants. But even if it only inlines inline definitions (which GCC with `-O1` does, IIRC), a definition can be both inline and external, as in your example. These modifiers combine, they don’t replace each other.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The definition in their example is not inline, as the C standard defines it. The `extern` effectively cancels the `inline`. An inline definition is a **separate** definition from a non-inline external definition, but using `extern inline void foo(void);` cancels that and makes the `inline void foo(void) { … }` the external definition.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But that’s irrelevant for inlining considerations. I’ve no idea what the standard intended (and, admittedly, despite knowing the C++ standard fairly well, my C standardese is rudimentary). But *in practice*, actual compilers still consider the `inline` specifier, so the modifiers stack. See https://godbolt.org/z/bcY888zjr.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: *In practice* people compile for deployment with `-O3` or `-Os`, each of which yields identical results between your with-`inline` and without-`inline` cases (but different from each other of course, as `-O3` inlines both for speed and `-Os` inlines neither for space).

Answer (score 2):

> … in this translation unit, we have the extern inline which actually changes the original inline definition of the function foo to an external definition and this cannot be used for inlining at all. Is this understanding correct?

This is correct; C 2018 6.7.4 7 says “… If all of the file scope declarations for a function in a translation unit include the `inline` function specifier without `extern`, then the definition in that translation unit is an *inline definition*…” Since the translation unit you show has a declaration for `foo` that has `extern` (it has `extern inline void foo(void);`), it does not satisfy those requirements in 6.7.4 7, so it does not qualify as an inline definition.

> My question is that how does the compiler perform the inlining when compiling with like -O1 flag since, after the preprocessing, the inline definition would be added to the source file,…

The C standard says nothing about how the compiler **does** perform inlining, just about what it **may** do. It says that if there were an inline definition, it would provide an alternative the compiler could choose: The compiler would be allowed by the C standard to use either the inline definition or the external definition.

It is easier to use `static inline`. Then the function is defined only for the current translation unit, and the function is an *inline function*, which suggests to the compiler the calls to the function be made fast (typically by integrating its code into the function that calls it).

For external inline functions, there should be one translation unit that provides an external non-inline definition (typically by defining the function in the normal way, without `inline`, and typically in a source file, not a header). Then every other translation unit that wants to have the option of using an inline version should have one inline definition (typically provided inside a header, not in the source file as you show), and that translation unit should not use `extern` in any of its declarations of the name of the function.

Comment: For your last paragraph, could you please show me an example of how to use the pattern you mentioned, I mean the external inline functions?

Comment: @Becavalier: An external non-inline definition would simply be an ordinary function definition in one source file. An inline definition would be, for example, `inline int foo(int x) { … }`, and it would usually be in a header file.